# kile auto-backspace while typing

Tags: kile

I just started using kile to work with latex and I'm having an odd problem. While typing, I might pause to think, and if there is whitespace behind the cursor, kile will automatically perform a backspace whenever I stop typing. It is pretty frustrating to see all the typing errors this causes.

At first I thought it might be something my OS was doing (Manjaro KDE), but the behavior only happens while using kile.

If this is a feature, I can't find out how to turn it off. I've looked through the kile configuration menus and tried disabling many options that could be related, but no success.

Also, I am using kile in Vi mode with live preview enabled if that helps.

Comment: Is this what is happening? You type in vi mode. You type something and after you type, you get out of the insert mode by pressing escape. When you want to type again, you press i, and suddenly a space is missing. If this is the case, you can press a (append) instead of i to go into insert mode. Append will move your cursor to one space on the right.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis No, this is what happens: I enter insert mode, start typing a sentence, pause for a fraction of a second, and if there's white-space behind the cursor position, it automatically performs a backspace. If there is any kind of character behind the cursor when I pause, it doesn't delete the character behind it. Also odd is this that I noticed: If I'm typing between curly braces and create the same conditions with a white space behind the cursor, no backspace will occur.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have this problem. It is caused by a setting in "Settings -> Configure Kile -> Live Preview"

By default, live preview will only compile documents after saving.

What causes this behavior is when you enable "Compile documents whenever there are changes after" By default it's set to 500ms. I enabled this behavior so every time I stop typing, the document will recompile. The issue with this is that when it compiles, the cursor position is returned to the last non-whitespace character on the current line. If you typically end your thoughts with a space after the last word (like I do), it will appear to do a backspace every time you stop typing.

Fix: Make sure "Compile documents after saving" is enabled instead.

Comment: Are you sure the space isn't being deleted? There is a setting which will remove end of line spaces every time you save. If this is enabled and autosave is enabled, you'd see this behaviour. But Kile doesn't delete end of line spaces if it isn't configured to do that. In that case, you can save without losing the final space.